# Como enviar valores com Zeros a esquerda SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server

Ao tentar enviar valores com zero a esquerda, ao verificar na base de dados recebo os valores em os zeros.
Ex: 000431, aparece na base de dados como 431.
Esse valor esta sendo colocado na variável $prefixo

Segue o codigo:

```
    <?php


$bomba1 = $_POST["bomba"]; 
$bomba = floatval($bomba1);

$prefixo1 = strval($_POST["prefixo"]);

$combustivel = $_POST["combustivel"];

$prefixo2 = str_pad($prefixo1, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$prefixo = substr($prefixo2, -5);     

echo $bomba ;
    echo $prefixo ;
    echo $combustivel ;

$serverName = "GALAXY\BDTL";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Abastecimento", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Abastecimento (prefixo, empresa) VALUES ($prefixo, 'TT' )";
//$params = array(1, "some data");

//$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{
    print_r("Gravação concluída");
}
?>
```

Comment: Se o tipo de dado é numérico então zeros à esquerda não são significativos. Se apenas deseja exibir com zeros à esquerda é só formatar adequadamente ao exibir.

Answer (score -1):

pode usar a função a seguir:

```
replicate(string expression, integer expression);
```

exemplo:

```
select empid,          
       replicate('0', 6 - len(salary)) + cast (salary as varchar) as salary
from   emp;  

empid       salary
----------- -----------
1           000300
2           000030
3           500000
4           001000

(4 row(s) affected)
```

segue a fonte desses exemplos:
https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30469/sql-server-how-to-left-pad-a-number-with-zeros/

---

Para o php utilize a função `str_pad`:

```
<?php
$input = "300";
print str_pad($input, 10);                      // produz "300     "
print str_pad($input, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // produz "0000000300"
print str_pad($input, 10, "0", STR_PAD_BOTH);   // produz "000300000"
print str_pad($input, 6 , "0");               // produz "300000"
?>
```

Comment: Opa, encontrei esse tipo de ajuda porém não sei se se aplica ao meu problema, me parece que esse exemplo seria pra alterar dentro do SQl, o que eu preciso é já enviar de formatado pelo PHP.

Comment: coloquei em php a função

Comment: Sim, isso esta no código que eu enviei, mas não funcionou bem.

Comment: cara faz o seguinte poe UNSIGNED na tabela do banco e usa a unção que passei pra sql que resolve. este é o jeito certo de se fazer pois ele alem de entender que é um INT ou FLOAT ou DECIMAL ( tanto faz ) vc pode fazer operações diretamente

Comment: @JasarOrion me parece uma ideia ruim alterar a tabela no banco para resolver um problema de código, fora que se o problema fosse só os zeros a esquerda significa que iria querer armazenar o valor como se fosse um texto, então o mais prático seria converter o campo para um `varchar/char` por exemplo

Comment: o problema q vc quer resolver parte é má modelagem do banco o fato de vc torna-lo UNSIGNED ja permite essa alteração sem que vc altere o tipo do campo.

Comment: @JasarOrion, realmente, nem posso alterar a base de dados.
Tentei converter porem quando dou  um echo no sql, percebo que não foi convertido para string.

Usei strval sem sucesso :/

Comment: Alguém com a solução ?